# Connecting to Snowflake ODBC via Linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

We're currently running SQL Server 2014. We need to ingest data from Snowflake.
Our goal is to fetch data/run queries using a linked server.

Here's the kicker - It needs to authenticate using Browser Authentication (System Admin will not provide me with a process/application ID/token). OAuth authentication is disabled.

I've installed the Snowflake ODBC driver on the server, which authenticates through a pop-up browser window which authenticates my First.LastName@Mydomain.com. This is how the ODBC set up appears:

[image]

When I try and set up the SQL linked server, the connection times out (presumably because

[image]

Any alternatives/workarounds?

Comment: It's a headless thing, so you probably can't use web auth in linked server.